# wordpress acf repeater mapping in custom field post not working

Tags: php, wordpress, mapping, advanced-custom-fields

After a long search on the net, my code didn't come up with what I wanted.
I with wordpress and acf , the purpose of the function is to return a mapped array from a costumed post type.
I created and saved the costum post type named 'myCpt' to which I linked it with acf type fields: (text and repeater)
I was able to retrieve the text value but I can't get the repeater values.... Thanks for seeing the var_dump() image

Your help will be very valuable to me.

```
class myClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        var_dump($this->get_all());
    }

    function get_all()
    {
        $args = array(

            'post_type' => 'myCpt',
            'posts_per_page' => 999,
            'post_status' => 'publish'

        );

        $myCpt = get_posts($args);

        $myCpt_mapped = array_map(function ($myCpt) {

            $id = $myCpt->ID;

            return array(
                'id' => $id,
                'title' => get_field('maintitle', $id, false),
                'subtitle' => get_field('subtitle', $id, false),
                // 'services' =>  services repeater
                'repField' => array(
                    'name' => get_sub_field('name', $id, false),
                    'img' => get_sub_field('img', $id, false)
                )
            );
        }, $myCpt);

        return array(
            'myCpt' => $myCpt_mapped
        );
    }
}
global $myClass;
$myClass = new $myClass();}
```

resultat:
[var_dump()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0io5.png)

Comment: All the examples on https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/ have this inside a loop that uses `the_row()` to set up the proper context, so likely you will have to do it in a similar fashion, otherwise the function won't know what the context is.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your reply .
Unfortunately, all these examples didn't help me, because I'm using this class in backend , and I'm using wordpress headless, and the generated array is to convert it to json and use it as endpoint at last

The good news is that I managed to insert the simple fields, a solution I can't find anywhere on the forums.
Proud to help the community, but unfortunately I can't get the repeater fields.

Comment: _"because I'm using this class in backend , and I'm using wordpress headless"_ - I don't see what that would have to do with anything. In what way is that stopping you from looping the same way as the basic example under https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/#examples shows? I am guessing the problem perhaps results from your attempt to handle all this "inside" `return array(...)`?  Don't do that then, build your base array first, then loop over your repeater field and _add_ values to the existing array in the correct positions.

Comment: And https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row/#example shows how to get the row data into a variable, if necessary, using an additional call of `get_row`.

Comment: @CBroe   I tried the following code from here 
[link]https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-all-fields-for-all-posts-in-one-array/)
I've had Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_userdata() 
if only you help me to complete the code above instead of referring me to the documentation ..I recovered the fields I still have the sub_fields
**it's almost done**
and thank you very much for your feedback

Comment: I don't see `get_userdata` in either the code you have shown here, nor anywhere in that discussion you just referred to.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for reply . Fatal error has been resolved.
Now I have an array with all the fields, I still have to apply an array_map 

`if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
// Get WPPost Object
$fields = get_post();// Get ACFfields
$acf_fields = get_fields($fields->ID);
array_push($services_posts, $fields);
array_push($all_acf_fields, $acf_fields);
   $i = 0;
foreach ($services_posts as $p) :
$p->acf_fields = $all_acf_fields[$i]; $i++;
endforeach;
endwhile;`

Comment: _"Now I have an array with all the fields, I still have to apply an array_map"_ - I don't know what exactly that is supposed to mean now. And extended codes in comments are hard to read, so please add this to your question, properly formatted. And show an example of what data you have now.